# How to pass back using information ajax POST request

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Currently I'm working on the slider, each slide is certain state using state machine. Now from one page I'm making post request with the data, which gets sent, if it passes validation, I would like to return "name of the state" to my view page, so I can move the slide ?

Is this better way of doing this ? The reason I chose slides as state so I can run query to figure out how many of my client made to certain slide.

So currently I'm making ajax post request.. (Ignore done for part)

```
$.post("/xxx/tracks", { name: "xx", time: "xx", pa: "xx" }).done(function(data) {
   alert("Data Loaded:" + data);
});
```

So now in my controller

```
def tracks
 binding.pry
 # some condition determining val accordingly
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { head :ok } #return val somehow
 end
end
```

so my question is how do I return some value back ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass  html, text or just the response header if you want to render nothing.

Html for example, just render the view you want:

```
def tracks
 binding.pry
 # some condition determining val accordingly
 render 'tracks' #tracks.html.erb
end

$.post("/xxx/tracks", { name: "xx", time: "xx", pa: "xx" }, function(data) {
  $("selector").append(data)
}).error(function(response, data){
  alert('error processing the request')
})
```

For Text:

```
def tracks
 binding.pry
 # some condition determining val accordingly
 if expression
   render text: 'success', status: :ok
 else
   render text: 'Error processing your request', status :bad_request
 end
end

$.post("/xxx/tracks", { name: "xx", time: "xx", pa: "xx" }, function(response, data) {
  alert(data.responseText)
}).error(function(response, data){
  alert(data.responseText)
})
```

To render just the headers

```
def tracks
 binding.pry
 # some condition determining val accordingly
 if expression
   head :created
 else
   head :unprocessable_entity
 end
end

$.post("/xxx/tracks", { name: "xx", time: "xx", pa: "xx" }, function() {
  alert('seccess')
}).error(function(){
  alert('error')
})
```

you can render too json data.